# set command with -- flag

Tags: shell-script

I have a file (called text) that contains two fields of strings (separated by space) like what follows:

```
1.2.3  version1
```

When I use set command as follows, I have the first field in the $1 and the second field in $2.
Can someone explain what this command does? In particular what < does? Is this an input redirection?

```
set -- $(<text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That command combines two rather special tricks...

**set --**

Usually `set` is used to configure shell options (see the man page of your shell). A special case is `set --`. This is used to set the positional parameters. Unfortunately I have forgotten what that was about but I once read about a problem which could not be solved well by other means.

**$(< file)**

`$(command)` is command subsitution: The shell collects the output on stdout and replaces `$(command)` by that output when executing the command line. If you need the content of a file you could do this: `$(cat file)`. `$(< file)` is just a short version of that, saving an unnecessary process (`cat`).

Comment: Just to clarify: `set 1.2.3 version1` would also set `$1` to `1.2.3` and `$2` to `version1`. The `--` tells `set` to stop accepting flags. That way, if the file `text` contained something along the lines of `-k version1`, `set` would not confuse the first field of the file's text for a flag.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman, `set --` tells `set` to stop accepting flags **and** to stop outputting all the variables when not passed any argument.